# Elixir coverage is mis-reporting a line

Tags: elixir, code-coverage

I have a simple module:

```
defmodule Issues.CLI do
    @default_count 4

    def run(argv) do
      parse_args(argv)
    end

    def parse_args(argv) do
      case OptionParser.parse(argv, switches: [help: :boolean], aliases: [h: :help]) do
        { _, [user, project, count], _ } -> {user, project, count}
        { _, [user, project], _ }        -> {user, project, @default_count}
        _                                -> :help
      end
    end
end
```

And several tests (espec) including this one:

```
      it "--help" do
        expect(Issues.CLI.parse_args(["--help"])) |> to(be :help)
      end
```

The test clearly calls the "catch all" case, and I verified it by commenting it out and see the test fail.

When I run the tests with coverage, this catch all case is shown as not covered and coverage is not at 100% as you would expect.
Note that I have tried both coverex and coveralls, with the same result.

I am new to Elixir, so I could be missing something obvious, but I really don't see why the line is not picked up in the coverage report and computation.

Comment: Looks like a bug. A clause in `case` where the body of a pattern doesn't use any variable from the pattern seems to not be considered as code for me. The line is completely skipped in the cover report, like it's a comment or other non-executable line.

Comment: That's a reasonable explanation. Thanks Dogbert. I will experiment to confirm and pay the results here.